ffmpeg with NVenc does not seem to utilize my GPU
I tried to convert a high-resolution video to 2k. I used this command:
ffmpeg -i input_video.mp4 -vf scale=1920:1080 -c:v h264_nvenc -preset slow -b:v 8M output_video.mp4

Based on the top and nvidia-semi results, my CPU was at maximum utilization, but my GPU was barely used. The ffmpeg process only used about 240 MiB of vram.
nvidia-smi dmon did show lots of enc activity. But the low vram usage and high CPU utilization makes me wonder if ffmpeg is fully utilize my GPU.
nvidia-smi dmon                                                                                     
# gpu    pwr  gtemp  mtemp     sm    mem    enc    dec    jpg    ofa   mclk   pclk
# Idx      W      C      C      %      %      %      %      %      %    MHz    MHz
    0      -     74      -      6      8     66      0      -      -   3504    420
    0      -     74      -      6      8     71      0      -      -   3504    420
    0      -     74      -      6      8     70      0      -      -   3504    420
    0      -     74      -      6      8     71      0      -      -   3504    420
    0      -     74      -      6      7     63      0      -      -   3504    420
    0      -     74      -      5      7     56      0      -      -   3504    420
    0      -     74      -      6      8     70      0      -      -   3504    420
    0      -     74      -      6      8     67      0      -      -   3504    420
    0      -     74      -      6      8     69      0      -      -   3504    420
    0      -     74      -      6      8     71      0      -      -   3504    420
    0      -     74      -      6      8     68      0      -      -   3504    420


@VlastimilBurián seeing that HandBrake uses libavformat/ffmpeg internally, and that for accelerated H.264 it uses the same Nvidia Nvenc encoder, I'm not convinced it can do magic there.

David, is your preset "slow" part of what you can pick from ffmpeg -h encoder=h264_nvenc ?

also, since your ffmpeg doesn't stop doing things, congratulations, you are using your GPU acceleration. It's natural that your CPU is still used – some things have to be done in software (e.g. packing into an output stream), and the fact that it uses as much CPU as it can get for these tasks is good, because it means just isn't bottlenecking on the GPU.

If you strictly speaking do not have to use command line for this operation, save yourself much trouble using HandBrake: https://handbrake.fr/

I am transcoding my BluRay library with it, using NVEnc (Nvidia encoder), specifically 10-bit H.265 hardware acceleration I backup my collection, there are really many settings which should be set in order for the encoder to do its job nicely to your needs...

As a side note, audio and couple other things must be done on CPU, so it is perfectly normal to have e.g. 90-95% CPU load on my work-laptop with Nvidia 1060 and i7-7700HQ CPU.
